# rails css compass grid with 100% width?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, blueprint-css

We have blueprint in compass, wich defaults to 950 pixels centered.

Im looking for a way to have full 100% width to create a layout like below image, is there a way to achieving this by hacking blueprint framework for compass or any other framework? I would want to use compass and blueprint with sass to generate the layouts.

- |---------|----------|
- | menu |
- | item2 |
- |---------|----------|
- <-- 100% width -->

the menu bar will contain some menu items and in the white left i would like to display the content, just a very rough idea. Using compass and blueprint this layout cannot be achieved.

Comment: So you want a 2 column layout, the menu on the left and the content on the right?

Comment: yes but then 100% width, not like blueprint 950px centered. haven't been abe to find any info on that

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a "fluid" layout, check this piece of documentation out, it should handle what you are looking to do.

http://compass-style.org/reference/blueprint/liquid/

Hope that helps.